# Error while importing arcpy in shell of 64bit geoprocessing arcgis ! python window crashes

Tags: arcpy, installation, arcgis-10.5, 64bit

[image]

I am using arcgis 10.5 on windows 10.

I am getting this error after importing arcpy in shell of 64 bit geoprocessing.

i have done a clean installation of arcgis and 64 bit geoprocessing but i am always getting this error.

can anybody please help me.

here is the text of my sys paths

```
    >>> import sys
    >>> print(sys.path)
    ['', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ArcGIS\\Desktop10.5\\arcpy', 
    'C:\\Python27\\ArcGISx6410.5\\ C:\\Python27\\ArcGISx6410.5\\Lib', 
    'C:\\Python27\\ArcGISx6410.5\\ C:\\Python27\\ArcGISx6410.5\\DLLs', 
    'C:\\Python27\\ArcGISx6410.5\\ C:\\Python27\\ArcGISx6410.5\\Lib\\lib-
    tk', 'C:\\Python27\\ArcGISx6410.5\\ C:\\WINDOWS\\system32', 
    'C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\python27.zip', 
    'C:\\Python27\\ArcGISx6410.5\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python27\\ArcGISx6410.5\\lib', 
    'C:\\Python27\\ArcGISx6410.5\\lib\\plat-win', 
    'C:\\Python27\\ArcGISx6410.5\\lib\\lib-tk', 
    'C:\\Python27\\ArcGISx6410.5', 'C:\\Python27\\ArcGISx6410.5\\lib\\site-
    packages', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ArcGIS\\Desktop10.5\\bin64', 
    'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ArcGIS\\Desktop10.5\\ArcToolBox\\Scripts']
```

I type this command in my shell

```
    >>>import arcpy
```

and the shell hangs and gives this result

[image: when i click on debug button]

Comment: Could you post the text of the error, so that it is searchable, as well as a screenshot that isn't your whole desktop? That's impossible to read.

Comment: use the snipping tool to snap a pic

Comment: i have updated the question and please click on image to zoom in

Comment: Consider why you're getting a 32bit exception if you're in a 64bit shell. I think you need to prune some of your paths so it's not finding the 32bit libs *before* the 64bit libs.

Comment: How do I remove 32 bit libraries I have already edited pythonpath with no success it is getting additional paths than pythonpath.